# Flutter Catch Statement Not Handling Firebase Exception Correctly

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I am trying to sign in to my flutter app, but it is exiting with an error. I am trying to sign in with the username 'abcdadsfasdf@gmail.com' and password '1239123'. This username does not exist in my firebase app, and when I try to sign in with it, it throws this error. The reason this error is happening is because 'user' is being returned as null, and when a null check is done on it, the code errors out. My question is - why is the catch statement not accurately catching the error?

**This is what the error looks like**

```
Exception has occurred.\
_CastError (Null check operator used on a null value)
```

**Here is the code for the function:**

```
Future<User?> signInWithEmailPassword(String email, String password) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  User? user;

  try {

    print('there');
```

**When the code does error, it gets to this await statement and crashes after the await statement has executed and failed**

```
    UserCredential userCredential = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: email,
      password: password,
    );
    print('before');
    user = userCredential.user;
    print('here');

    if (user != null) {
      uid = user.uid;
      userEmail = user.email;

      SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      await prefs.setBool('auth', true);
      prefs.setString('id', user.uid);
    }
  } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
    if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
      print('No user found for that email.');
    } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
      print('Wrong password provided.');
    }
  }

  return user;
}
```

As you can see, the exception should be handled and caught, but for some reason it just errors and never gets caught correctly. Why is this happening?

EDIT: The reason this is happening is because the user is returned as null, causing that error to be thrown. However the catch should catch this error, making me really confused.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest/326582#326582

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint and used the debugger to step through?

Comment: I don't understand how to do that in flutter. Do you mind referencing an article for me?

Comment: It will depend on the IDE you are using. Android studio or VS Code etc.

Comment: I figured out why the error was occurring Paul, (question updated accordingly), but the error handling part is still wrong, and I don't know why. Can you help me with that new updated question or do you need more info? Thanks! (Oh also I am using VS Code)               EDIT (More clarification): The error is occurring in the try catch block but doesn't catch correctly

Comment: Most likely the error that is being thrown *isn't* a FirebaseAuthException. Use a more general catch

Comment: Alright I'll try that in a sec. Thanks!