# Flutter Dev Issue

Tags: android, ios, flutter, firebase, dart

I am developing an app in flutter. There is an issue that occurs when I try to sign in using firebase authentication (by email and password). The error that is occuring is:

```
Exception has occurred.
_CastError (Null check operator used on a null value)
```

I have no clue why my code all of a sudden stopped working, and no idea where this error even is occurring. I have pinpointed where in my code the issue is, but the thing is I am referencing firebase's authentication service and that is where the issue lies. Here is the problematic function:

```
Future<User?> signInWithEmailPassword(String email, String password) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  User? user;

  try {
    UserCredential userCredential = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: email,
      password: password,
    );
    user = userCredential.user;

    if (user != null) {
      uid = user.uid;
      userEmail = user.email;

      SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      await prefs.setBool('auth', true);
     // prefs.setString('id', user.uid);
    }
  } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
    if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
      print('No user found for that email.');
    } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
      print('Wrong password provided.');
    }
  }

  return user;
}
```

ISSUE: In the first line of the try block, there is an await on the _auth function. This throws the error above. Here is the full code of the entire authentication program:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart' show kIsWeb;

final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

String? uid;
String? name;
String? userEmail;
String? imageUrl;

/// For checking if the user is already signed into the
/// app using Google Sign In
Future getUser() async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  bool? authSignedIn = prefs.getBool('auth');
  print(authSignedIn);

  final User? user = _auth.currentUser;

  if (authSignedIn == true) {
    if (user != null) {
      uid = user.uid;
      name = user.displayName;
      userEmail = user.email;
      imageUrl = user.photoURL;
      prefs.setString('name', name!);
      prefs.setString('id', uid!);
    }
  }
}

/// For authenticating user using Google Sign In
/// with Firebase Authentication API.
///
/// Retrieves some general user related information
/// from their Google account for ease of the login process
Future<User?> signInWithGoogle() async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  User? user;

  if (kIsWeb) {
    GoogleAuthProvider authProvider = GoogleAuthProvider();

    try {
      final UserCredential userCredential =
          await _auth.signInWithPopup(authProvider);

      user = userCredential.user;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  } else {
    final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

    final GoogleSignInAccount? googleSignInAccount =
        await googleSignIn.signIn().catchError((onError) => print(onError));;

    if (googleSignInAccount != null) {
      final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
          await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

      final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
        idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
      );

      try {
        final UserCredential userCredential =
            await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);

        user = userCredential.user;
      } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
        if (e.code == 'account-exists-with-different-credential') {
          print('The account already exists with a different credential.');
        } else if (e.code == 'invalid-credential') {
          print('Error occurred while accessing credentials. Try again.');
        }
      } catch (e) {
        print(e);
      }
    }
  }

  if (user != null) {
    uid = user.uid;
    name = user.displayName;
    userEmail = user.email;
    imageUrl = user.photoURL;

    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setBool('auth', true);
    //prefs.setString('id', user.uid);
    //prefs.setString('name', user.displayName!);
  }

  return user;
}

Future resetPassword(String email) async {
  try {
    print(email);
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.sendPasswordResetEmail(email: email);
  } on FirebaseAuthException catch(e) {
    print(e);
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

Future<User?> registerWithEmailPassword(String email, String password) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  User? user;

  try {
    UserCredential userCredential = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: email,
      password: password,
    );

    user = userCredential.user;

    if (user != null) {
      uid = user.uid;
      userEmail = user.email;

      //SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      //prefs.setString('id', user.uid);
      //prefs.setString('name', user.displayName!);
    }
  } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
    if (e.code == 'weak-password') {
      print('The password provided is too weak.');
    } else if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
      print('The account already exists for that email.');
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }

  return user;
}

Future<User?> signInWithEmailPassword(String email, String password) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  User? user;

  try {
    UserCredential userCredential = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: email,
      password: password,
    );
    user = userCredential.user;

    if (user != null) {
      uid = user.uid;
      userEmail = user.email;

      SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      await prefs.setBool('auth', true);
     // prefs.setString('id', user.uid);
    }
  } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
    if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
      print('No user found for that email.');
    } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
      print('Wrong password provided.');
    }
  }

  return user;
}

Future<String> signOut() async {
  await _auth.signOut();

  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  prefs.setBool('auth', false);

  uid = null;
  userEmail = null;

  return 'User signed out';
}

/// For signing out of their Google account
void signOutGoogle() async {
  await googleSignIn.signOut();
  await _auth.signOut();

  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  prefs.setBool('auth', false);

  uid = null;
  name = null;
  userEmail = null;
  imageUrl = null;

  print("User signed out of Google account");
}
```

Thank you so much! This issue is super annoying and I have been dealing with it for 3 days now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code seems ok except for the fact `Firebase.initializeApp()` is everywhere.

This `Firebase.initializeApp()` is a one time call and ideally should be added as below in the main function.

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
```

Getting back to the error:

`(Null check operator used on a null value)`

```
 //check with a print statement the value `user.uid` 
 //here to confirm user is returned successfully

if (user != null) {
  uid = user.uid;
  userEmail = user.email;
```

Very likely the user is null here.
if yes, make sure Firebase is initialised properly and go to Firebase console Authentication page to check if user is created and/or logged in

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer Niladri! I figured out the issue in the end, but I do have another very similar issue. If you go to my other question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75903859/flutter-catch-statement-not-handling-firebase-exception-correctly, the problem is that the catch statement was not handling the error correctly. When I enter the wrong username/pswd, it should catch the error but instead it errors out and crashes the app. Can you please take a look? You seem to know more about Flutter than I do. Thanks!

Comment: I also marked your answer as correct because I will delete this question soon and want you to get the reputation for being the only person to answer :(